# Cannot see local multiplayer worlds in MCPE 0.14.0

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Me and my sister both have IPads and are both up to date on MCPE and both have multiplayer and LAN on but, when we click the 'play' button we can't see that the other players world (that they are on).

Answer (score 1):

You can play with each other by using the following steps:

1. Turn on the hotspot of your any device.
2. Connect your other device with it.
3. Open Minecraft in any device and play any world.
4. Open Minecraft in the other device and select 'Play' button.
5. Wait for 5 seconds and you will be able to see the local world.
6. Enjoy!